# Storing an "array" to wp theme options?

Tags: wordpress

I've created a bit complex theme, which includes a slider. However, the slider needs to have multiple slides (of course), so I'm wondering, how to save them to wp-db.

Should I just create another table for the slider? I *could* do this, which sucks:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+
| Slide1 | only-image|http://google.com/logo.png |
| Slide2 | text-on-left|Text|img-url             |
| Slide3 | text-on-bottom|Text|img-url           |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

Thanks,
Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use custom post type. That way I could keep editing features of wp and have a slider. :)
Of course I guess that you want to edit slides, or that you want users to have option to edit slides.